# Google maps API v3 - Marker disappears after setPosition

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, marker

I'm having a problem with the maps markers. The map and marker load fine on the inital pageload. But when I try to update the marker location it simply disappears. The Alert window gives the correct coördinates. What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $loc; ?>);

function initialize()
{
  var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $loc; ?>),
  zoom:15,    
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
,mapProp);
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
position:myCenter,
});

marker.setMap(map);                 

setInterval(function(){ 
    jQuery.get('loc.php?v=<?php echo $_GET['voertuignummer'];?>', function(data) {
alert(data);
position = new google.maps.LatLng(data);
marker.setPosition(position);
map.setCenter(position);
    });

}, 15000);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: What does `alert(data)` show?

Comment: the GPS coördinates. It's obtained from a PHP file.

Example: 51.8234875663, 5.79311138367

So that's the strange thing. In 'data', the correct GPS value is present. However, when I sent those GPS coördinates to the marker, it disappears. 

I also tried map.setcenter to the value of data, but then the map turns grey.

Comment: It is (probably) the "correct" GPS value, but seen from a google.maps.LatLng point of view, it is nothing but a string.

Comment: @geocodezip, marking as duplicate two hours after an accepted answer does not make any sense.

Comment: Is it not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function(data) {
   alert(data);
   position = new google.maps.LatLng(data);
   ..
```

Looks *very* wrong; `data` is a string, probably containing `"lat, lng"`, which `google.maps.LatLng` cannot be initialized with. [`new google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLng) requires a pair of type `number` in the arguments, like `(number, number)`.

Do this instead :

```
data = data.split(',');
position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data[0]), parseFloat(data[1]));
```

Comment: Of course! I didn't think of that because the initial load with the same info worked. Jquery get returns it as a string. Do'h! Thanks!