# Google maps marker disapears after reloading

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a travel portal with places marked by google map markers. I have a JSON file with data, I load it by jQuery getJSON and in .done() I make a loop to create all markers like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[APIKEY]"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4717161, 21.4709998),
      zoom: 11
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  }
  </script>
  <style>
    html, body, #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()">
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
      }
    }
  });

  $.getJSON("js/data.json")
  .done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
      });
      marker.setMap(map);
    });
  })
  .fail(function() {
    var content = '<p>Błąd wczytywania danych!</p>';
    $('#sidebar').html(content);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main problem is that the markers shows once at first loading but after reloading page they disapear. The problem is in the Google Chrome 63, Firefox 57.04.

Is this problem caused by that the loop is in the .done() method?

I tried solutions from this post [Google maps API v3 - Marker disappears after setPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854459/google-maps-api-v3-marker-disappears-after-setposition) but not works.

I readed [google maps move marker with lat/lng from ajax success returned data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654989/google-maps-move-marker-with-lat-lng-from-ajax-success-returned-data) too.

Here is a data from file:

```html
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "category": "preserve",
      "title": "Rezerwat Miodne",
      "description": "Lorem psum dolor sit amet...",
      "latitude": "51.3789751",
      "longitude": "21.4606515",
      "photo": "miodne-splash.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "category": "preserve",
      "title": "Rezerwat Okólny Ług",
      "description": "Lorem psum dolor sit amet...",
      "latitude": "51.4302652",
      "longitude": "21.570949",
      "photo": "lugi-helenowskie-splash.jpg"
    }
  ]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: your code is not working in snippet. Please provide working code.

Comment: Do you have a valid key? I can see this warning: InvalidKey

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete I don't think the key is the problem, He might have removed it since its a bad idea to "publish" he's key.

Comment: Yes I removed the key due to security reasons.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data (3 or 4 location, mostly to see the formating )? Maybe there is a cache problem.  See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391563/how-to-set-cache-false-for-getjson-in-jquery